# Update with 2 joins

Tags: oracle, sql-update, inner-join

I'm trying to update data in 2 distinct tables in the same query with the following code:

```
UPDATE (SELECT s.passNumb, a.hour, a.minute, p.number, s.situation
        FROM passwords s
        JOIN atend a ON s.passNumb = a.passNumb
        JOIN points p ON a.number = p.number
        WHERE s.passNumb = 1 AND 
              p.number = 1)
  SET a.hour = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24'),
      a.minute = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MI'),
      s.situation = 'F';
```

But I'm getting this error: `Cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view with a join (or an inline view containing a join in your case) must meet the following conditions to be updatable:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm

> **If you want a join view to be updatable, then all of the following
>   conditions must be true:**
>
> **The DML statement must affect only one table underlying the join.**
>
> For an INSERT statement, the view must not be created WITH CHECK
>   OPTION, and all columns into which values are inserted must come from
>   a key-preserved table. A key-preserved table is one for which every
>   primary key or unique key value in the base table is also unique in
>   the join view.
>
> **For an UPDATE** statement, the view must not be created WITH CHECK
>   OPTION, and **all columns updated must be extracted from a key-preserved
>   table.**

---

The first condition is rather obvious: `The DML statement must affect only one table underlying the join.`

But what does it mean: "**key preserved table**" ?

> A key-preserved table is one for which every primary key or unique
>   key value in the base table is also unique in the join view.

The key preserved table means that each row from this table will appear **at most once** in the result of a view.
Consider a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id int primary key,
  user_name varchar(100),
  age int
);

insert into users values(1,'Tom', 22);

CREATE TABLE emails(
  user_id int,
  email varchar(100)
);

Insert into emails values( 1, 'tom@somedomain.com' );
Insert into emails values( 1, 'tom@www.example.org' );
commit;
```

And a join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
JOIN emails e ON u.user_id = e.user_id;

   USER_ID USER_NAME              AGE    USER_ID EMAIL              
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 Tom                     22          1 tom@somedomain.com   
         1 Tom                     22          1 tom@www.example.org
```

If you look at a result of this join, it is apparent that:

- user_id, user_name and age come from non-key preserved table
- email comes from key-preserved table

---

And now: this update is acceptable, because it updates a key preserved column (table) in this join:

```
    UPDATE (
      SELECT * FROM users u
      JOIN emails e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
    )
    SET email = email || '.it' ; 

   USER_ID USER_NAME              AGE    USER_ID EMAIL                   
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------
         1 Tom                     22          1 tom@somedomain.com.it     
         1 Tom                     22          1 tom@www.example.org.it
```

---

But this update cannot be done, since it touches a column from non-key preserved table:

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT * FROM users u
  JOIN emails e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
)
SET age = age + 2; 

SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

---

If you think a while .... Tom appears 2 times in the result of the join (but there is only one Tom in the `users` table).
When we are trying to update `age = age + 2` in this join, then what should be a result of this update ? 
Should Tom be updated only once ?
Should Tom be 22+2 = 24 years old after this update ? 
Or maybe Tom should be updated twice (since it appears twice in the result of the join) so it should be 22 + 2 + 2 = 26 years old.
Another example - please tell me what should be an outcome of this update?:

```
UPDATE ( ....our join ... ) SET age = length( email );
```

There are very difficult questions :) 
And because of this Oracle prevents from updating non-key preserved tables.

---

The error message gives this hint:
`*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.`
This means that we must update this table directly, using a separate UPDATE command:

```
  UPDATE users SET age = age + 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got it.